# Using std::bad_function_call with LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libc++

I am trying to build a native library in my Android Studio project that uses the [`std::bad_function_call`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call) function.

Here's the `CMakeLists.txt` file I use to build my native module:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(src/main/cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti -D_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE")

add_library(
    MyLib
    SHARED
    src/main/cpp/test.cpp
)
```

and my `test.cpp` contains the following code:

```
void SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
    std::function<int()> f = nullptr;
    try {
        f();
    } catch (const std::bad_function_call& e) {
    }
}
```

with the corresponding build.gradle section:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_NDK_ROOT=${android.ndkDirectory}"
    }
}
```

If I pass the `_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE` flag to the compiler I get a link error:

```
Execution failed for task ':runtime:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\android-sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\work\android-runtime\test-app\runtime\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a --target MyLib}
  [1/1] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a\libMyLib.so
  FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi17 --gcc-toolchain=C:/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fPIC --sysroot C:/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-addrsig -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++  -fno-rtti -D_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE -Oz -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libMyLib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a\libMyLib.so CMakeFiles/MyLib.dir/src/main/cpp/test.cpp.o  ../../../../src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/abc.a -llog -latomic -lm && cd ."
  C:/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:0: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::__ndk1::bad_function_call'

  C:/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function

  C:/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:0: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::bad_function_call::~bad_function_call()'

  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

If I remove the `_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE` flag:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti")
```

then the project compiles fine.

So my question is what would be the proper way to enable the [`libc++ unstable abi`](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/ABIVersioning.html) and use the `bad_function_call` method inside my native module?

Note: I am using Android NDK 19.

Comment: If `_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE` is defined, the `__config` STL header will define `_LIBCPP_ABI_BAD_FUNCTION_CALL_KEY_FUNCTION`. This is turn results in a couple of extra method being declared inside the `bad_function_class` in the `functional` header. But for those methods to also be _defined_ you would've had to build the STL itself with the same flag. And judging by the linker errors, it seems like the prebuilt libc++ that comes with the NDK was _not_ built with that flag.

Comment: @Michael, this makes perfect sense. If I build the STL myself what would be the proper way to specify it in `CMakeLists.txt` to use the custom library instead of the `-stdlib=libc++` flag? Also any pointers on how to build the STL for android?

Comment: Sorry, that's not something I've ever attempted.